# How to pass the return type of a function to an exception in OCaml?

Tags: exception, ocaml, return-type

I have function 'my_a' in OCaml, which could have a very complicated return type:

```
exception Backtrack
exception Continue of (* How do I put the type of function 'my_a' here? *)

let my_a arg = try do_stuff (List.hd arg) 
               with 
               | Backtrack -> my_a (List.tl arg)
               | Continue (found_answer) ->  (try my_a (List.tl arg)
                                              with 
                                     | Backtrack -> raise Continue(found_answer)
                                     | Continue (other_answer) -> 
                       raise Continue (compare_answer(found_answer,other_answer));;
(* the caller of my_a will handle the Continue exception to catch the found value
if something was found*)
```

This is my problem: I'm using backtrack to find a solution. When a backtrack exception is raised by do_stuff, there was no solution going that path. However, when it raises an exception of type Continue, it means it found a solution, but, it may not be the best solution there is, that's when I try again with a different path. If there is another exception, I want to return the answer it already had found.

The thing is, to be able to use that feature of OCaml I need to to tell it what data type Continue will be carrying. What the OCaml top level returns when i define my_a:

```
   'a * ('a -> ('a, 'b) symbol list list) ->
  'b list -> ('a * ('a, 'b) symbol list) list * 'b list = <fun>
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to do that, or a different solution to that?

Comment: You should tell us what problem you are trying to solve. Since you think that function names can start with a capital letter, and at the same time you are using exceptions in a highly unconventional way, we can help you much better if you allow us to tell you how to solve your original problem, rather than ask us a specific technical question about return types.

Comment: Hi, I provided more info, I hope you can help me

Comment: This sounds wrong. If `Continue` already happened, and then another `Continue` happens, your function will return the result found by the first `Continue`, but you say in the text that you should compare both solutions found so that you can use the better one. In any case, you shouldn't be structuring your program around exceptions like this.

Comment: Since you cannot know the best solution until you have searched the whole space, this is just an exhaustive search. Or do you intend to prune the search at some point?

Comment: Alright, I do intend to return the best solution, ignoring any other alternative. I guess I should display a bit more info on my idea. The thing is I'm kind of stuck with not being able to fully implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are gaining nothing by using exceptions. Here is a possible solution.

```
(** There are many ways to implement backtracking in Ocaml. We show here one
    possibility. We search for an optimal solution in a search space. The
    search space is given by an [initial] state and a function [search] which
    takes a state and returns either

    - a solution [x] together with a number [a] describing how good [x] is
      (larger [a] means better solution), or

    - a list of states that need still to be searched.

    An example of such a problem: given a number [n], express it as a sum
    [n1 + n2 + ... + nk = n] such that the product [n1 * n2 * ... * nk] is
    as large as possible. Additionally require that [n1 <= n2 <= ... <= nk].
    The state of the search can be expressed as pair [(lst, s, m)] where
    [lst] is the list of numbers in the sum, [s] is the sum of numbers in [lst],
    and [m] is the next number we will try to add to the list. If [s = n] then
    [lst] is a solution. Otherwise, if [s + m <= n] then we branch into two states:

    - either we add [m] to the list, so the next state is [(m :: lst, m+s, m)], or
    - we do not add [m] to the list, and the next state is [(lst, s, m+1)].

    The return type of [search] is described by the following datatype:
*)

type ('a, 'b, 'c) backtrack =
  | Solution of ('a * 'b)
  | Branches of 'c list

(** The main function accepts an initial state and the search function. *)
let backtrack initial search =
  (* Auxiliary function to compare two optional solutions, and return the better one. *)
  let cmp x y =
    match x, y with
      | None, None -> None (* no solution *)
      | None, Some _ -> y  (* any solution is better than none *)
      | Some _, None -> x  (* any solution is better than none *)
      | Some (_, a), Some (_, b) ->
        if a < b then y else x
  in
  (* Auxiliary function which actually performs the search, note that it is tail-recursive.
     The argument [best] is the best (optional) solution found so far, [branches] is the
     list of branch points that still needs to be processed. *)
  let rec backtrack best branches =
    match branches with
      | [] -> best (* no more branches, return the best solution found *)
      | b :: bs ->
        (match search b with
          | Solution x ->
            let best = cmp best (Some x) in
              backtrack best bs
          | Branches lst ->
            backtrack best (lst @ bs))
  in
    (* initiate the search with no solution in the initial state *)
    match backtrack None [initial] with
      | None -> None (* nothing was found *)
      | Some (x, _) -> Some x (* the best solution found *)

(** Here is the above example encoded. *)
let sum n =
  let search (lst, s, m) =
    if s = n then
      (* solution found, compute the product of [lst] *)
      let p = List.fold_left ( * ) 1 lst in
        Solution (lst, p)
    else
      if s + m <= n then
        (* split into two states, one that adds [m] to the list and another
           that increases [m] *)
        Branches [(m::lst, m+s, m); (lst, s, m+1)]
      else
        (* [m] is too big, no way to proceed, return empty list of branches *)           
        Branches []
  in
    backtrack ([], 0, 1) search
;;

(** How to write 10 as a sum of numbers so that their product is as large as possible? *)
sum 10 ;; (* returns Some [3; 3; 2; 2] *)
```

OCaml happily informs us that the type of `backtrack` is

```
'a -> ('a -> ('b, 'c, 'a) backtrack) -> 'b option
```

This makes sense:

- the first argument is the initial state, which has some type `'a`
- the second argument is the search function, which takes a state of type `'a` and
  returns either a `Solution (x,a)` where `x` has type `'b` and `a` has type `'c`,
  or `Branches lst` where `lst` has type `'a list`.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. I think you might be asking how to get the type inside the `Two` exception to be set to the return type of A without having to specifically declare this type. I can't think of any way to do it.

Things might go better if you used option types instead of exceptions. Or you can just declare the return type of A explicitly. It might be good documentation.

A couple of side comments: (a) function names have to start with a lower case letter (b) this code looks quite convoluted and hard to follow. There might be a simpler way to structure your computation.

Comment: "Not being able to write the type down" looks like a design smell that I think should rather be confronted than avoided through other tricks to get more inference. The type structure of a program is as important as its term structure, and if inference allows us to avoid redundancy, it should not be used to *lose control* on it whatsoever. Define type synonyms to capture the domain abstractions, and then a type should not be globally unpalatable.